# Javascript, counting in seconds - adding a point each time

Tags: javascript, html, project

So I am working on a project of mine and I'd like some help.

I'd like javascript to be able to count in seconds, each second it'd add a preset amount of points.

```
var total_points = 0
var points_per_click = 1
var points_per_second = 0

function points_per_second() {
docuement.getElementById("current_points").innerHTML("Current Points: " + total_points);
//insert here?
}
```

I would also like the points_per_second to be able to add into the total_points var. Thanks!

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docuement` is spelt "document", `.innerHTML` is not a function call (set it like a variable) & variables and functions share the same namespace, ***i.e.***  don't set a variable `points_per_second` and then declare a function of the same name.

Once you have your syntax errors sorted, you were probably looking for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval).

```
var total_points = 0;
var points_per_click = 1;
var points_per_second = 2;

function update_display(){
    var el = document.getElementById("current_points");
    el.innerHTML = "Current Points: " + total_points;
    //insert here? ... No
}

var ticker = setInterval(function(){
    total_points += points_per_second; 
    // ... or whatever your intended logic
    update_display();
}, 1000);
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hN2e/1/)